# How to interrupt while using apply function on a pandas dataframe python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to use the `apply` function to calculate a new column for a `pandas` `dataframe` but "interrupt" it based on some criteria.

Say I have a dataframe with 2000 rows and my criteria, which is dependent on the previously calculated applied values, turns to `false` at the 1000-th. Calculating the next 1000 is a waste and I would want `pandas` to stop "applying" after the 1000-th and give me back what it's calculated so far.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi.  Curious if you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: cannot remember sorry

Answer (score 0):

to use apply with a condition

```
df['new']=df['old'].apply(lambda x: <calculation> if <condition>(ex : x == 0) else x )
```

or

```
df.loc[df['col']=='value','col']= df.loc[df['col']=='value','col'].apply(lambda x: "new_value"  )
```

Comment: Thks for replying. The criteria itself will depend on the previously calculated applied values : how would your solution work in that case?

Comment: what is this criteria ?

Comment: The details of the criteria are not important. Let's say it uses all the previously calculated values at each new row and a function returns a boolean based on that.

Comment: the question is can I use the `df['new']` values calculated up to that point within my `<condition>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply on only rows that **you want**.

Let's say your index is auto incrementing and continuous, if not you can always perform `reset_index` to achieve that. Or you can choose whatever condition you want, rather than first 1000 rows.

```
idx = df.index < 1000 # index of 1000 items

df.loc[idx, '<yourcolums>'] = df[idx].apply(...)
```

Comment: Thks for replying. The criteria itself will depend on the previously calculated applied values : how would your solution work in that case?

Comment: Just replace `idx = <what ever your condition is>`, e.g: `idx = df['name'].str.startswith('Peter') # rows have col name start with Peter`

Comment: can the `name` column in your example be the column that I am currently calculating with the apply ?

Comment: it could be anything.

Comment: I can't define `idx` in your example since the apply has not run yet. My criteria is issued from the result of the apply function.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I thought you were overriding an existing column. So you want to filter on a not-yet-created column? No, not possible. Use the data availabe up to that command.

Comment: Let's say I initialize that column with a default value and then I override it with the apply. Any way to do what I want in that case?

Comment: You can use the column, but I don't see any use in that. E.g: What is the point of using column `temp_col`, with value is `0` in your `apply` function?

Comment: so apply does not work sequentially ? as in, at every step it's running, I cannot access the already calculated values in that column ?